# 2D array arguments to multiple functions in Excel

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, excel-formula

I'm looking to implement a function (combination of functions) to count the number of occurrences of a particular string in every 2nd row of a table.

Here's a sample of what I'd like the table to look like eventually:

|  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ali | X | Y | Z |
| Beth | Y | Z | Z |
| Ali | Z | X | Z |
| Beth | Z | Z | X |
|  |  |  |  |
| XY Tot |  |  |  |
| Ali | 3 |  |  |
| Beth | 2 |  |  |

So far, I have this function

```
SUMPRODUCT((MOD(ROW(A1:D5)-ROW($A$2),2)=0)*OR(A1:D5="X",A1:D5="Y"))
```

for Ali and the `$A$2` would be replaced by `$A$3` for Beth (I'm aware that I could probably use a `VLOOKUP` for filtering out Ali and Beth's rows, but I'm okay with a little sloppiness in that portion of the solution) but it only appears to be counting the rows themselves, so for Ali and Beth, it would simply output 2. My suspicion is that I'm misunderstanding how Excel handles the two separate functions with 2D array arguments.

Any help towards a properly functioning solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use the names: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="Ali")*((B1:D5="X")+(B1:D5="Y")>0))`

Comment: I think I should be able to simply use `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="Ali")*((B1:D5="X")+(B1:D5="Y")))`, since the two (+) operands should never be 1 simultaneously, right?